# C# Rx DistinctUntilChanged() for ANY result including List

Tags: c#, list, system.reactive

I am wrapping some API calls to pretend a socket result - looping the call with few seconds interval and emit the result when changed.

It works well when using `DistinctUntilChanged()` operator. However, when the result is a list, the operator always emit the result because it is distinct with the default comparer.

This is my custom observable for repeating a task with some delay no matter success or failed.

```
public class TaskRepeatObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private readonly Func<Task<T>> _taskFactory;
    private readonly TimeSpan _repeatDelayTimeSpan;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Func<Exception, bool> _onError;
    public TaskRepeatObservable(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory, TimeSpan repeatDelayTimeSpan = default(TimeSpan), Func<Exception, bool> onError = null)
    {
        _logger = new Log4NetLogger(GetType());
        _logger.IsEnabled = false;

        _taskFactory = taskFactory;
        _repeatDelayTimeSpan = repeatDelayTimeSpan;
        _onError = onError;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var result = await _taskFactory();
                        observer.OnNext(result);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.Error(e, "Observable Error: " + e.Message);
                        if (_onError != null && !_onError.Invoke(e))
                            throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (_repeatDelayTimeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero)
                                await Task.Delay(_repeatDelayTimeSpan, cancellationToken);
                        }
                        catch (TaskCanceledException)
                        {
                            // ignored
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                observer.OnError(e);
            }

            _logger.Debug("Observable is cancelled.");
        }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        });
    }
}
```

This is the extension to wrap the api calls.

```
public static class ObservableBuilder
{
    ///<summary>
    ///<para>Convert Task to Observable and emit only changed result, it's useful to wrap the api as socket-like.</para>
    ///</summary>
    public static IObservable<T> Repeat<T>(this Func<Task<T>> taskFactory, TimeSpan delay = default(TimeSpan),
        Func<Exception, bool> onError = null)
    {
        return new TaskRepeatObservable<T>(taskFactory, delay, onError).DistinctUntilChanged();
    }
```

My question is - how to make the `DistinctUntilChanged()` working for ANY result including `List` or `Enumerable`.

Noted that I have tried to implement my own comparer. But I still don't know how to check the type of `T` to select the proper comparer for `DistinctUntilChanged()`

```
public class IEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y) || x != null && y != null && x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        // Will not throw an OverflowException
        unchecked
        {
            return obj.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the simple testing code:

```
        ObservableBuilder.Repeat(async () =>
        {
            var i = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            return i;
        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ToHotObservable().Subscribe(x => Logger.Info($"Result = {x}"));
```

I expect the result only be emitted once for list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have just one `Repeat` function which convers all cases but works differently for `IEnumerable`s - you have to use some reflection. You need to check if type `T` implements `IEnumerable<Something>` and if so - use special comparer for `DistinctUtilChanged` - otherwise use default comparer.

First it won't hurt to modify signature of your `EnumerableComparer` a bit, because you will need specifically `IEqualityComparer<T>`, not `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>`:

```
private class EnumerableComparer<T, TItem> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : IEnumerable<TItem> {
    public bool Equals(T x, T y) {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y) || x != null && y != null && x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj) {
        // Will not throw an OverflowException
        unchecked {
            return obj.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to check if `T` is `IEnumerable` and create instance of this comparer via reflection:

```
public static class ObservableBuilder {
    public static IObservable<T> Repeat<T>(this Func<Task<T>> taskFactory, TimeSpan delay = default(TimeSpan),
        Func<Exception, bool> onError = null) {
        var ienum = typeof(T).GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsGenericType && c.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
        if (ienum != null) {
            // implements IEnumerable - create instance of comparer and use
            var comparer = (IEqualityComparer<T>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnumerableComparer<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), ienum.GenericTypeArguments[0]));
            return new TaskRepeatObservable<T>(taskFactory, delay, onError).DistinctUntilChanged(comparer);
        }
        // otherwise - don't use
        return new TaskRepeatObservable<T>(taskFactory, delay, onError).DistinctUntilChanged();
    }

    private class EnumerableComparer<T, TItem> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : IEnumerable<TItem> {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y) {
            return ReferenceEquals(x, y) || x != null && y != null && x.SequenceEqual(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj) {
            // Will not throw an OverflowException
            unchecked {
                return obj.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create `IEqualityComparer<T>` which will check every time if `x` and `y` implement `IEnumerable<Something>` and compare accordingly, but I'd expect it to be less efficient to do that on every comparision compared to just once when building sequence.

Comment: I am thinking if there is any other solution avoid using reflection.

Comment: I have implemented my own DeepComparer (I post it as another answer), but I don't know if this is any drawback or performance issue. Any comments?

Comment: @shtse8 you can only figure it out by testing I think. With collections of sizes you are actually using. There is some boxing involved in general-purpose comparer, but probably that's not a problem. So I'd use whatever you like more and be done with it, unless you will really struggle with perfomance, in which case you should measure. But for most purposes difference in perfomance (if any) in these solutions doesn't matter.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Notice that we need to check the T also, not only the interfaces of T.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answer by Evk. Instead of using reflection, I have tried to implement a more general comparer. But I don't know if this is any drawback using this comparer. So I just give it as a choice for anyone facing the same issue.

```
public class DeepComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        // Compare the Reference
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y) ||
               // Using Default Comparer to comparer the value
               EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y) ||
               // If they both are list, Compare using Sequenece Equal
               x is IEnumerable enumerableX &&
               y is IEnumerable enumerableY &&
               enumerableX.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(enumerableY.Cast<object>());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return obj is IEnumerable enumerable
                ? enumerable.Cast<object>()
                    .Select(e => e.GetHashCode())
                    .Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b)
                : obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```